# Don't come here " dressed like this vs Dressing like this

Tags: grammar, word-choice

What is the difference between Don't come here dressed like this vs Dressing like this.?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the donning of the clothing happens before the wearer arrives. Thus *dressed* is correct. The only sense I can make out of using *dressing* here is a situation in which the person addressed is in the process of donning the clothing at the time of their arrival. And that seems odd.

Comment: +1 for the chuckle

Comment: 'I wasn't really surprised to see him dressing like this' is unremarkable to my (UK) ears, so I'd say the present-participial variant (arguably a complement on semantic grounds) is not incorrect per se. Here, the default sense is not that the speaker sees the process of dressing, but that the style of dressing is durative (for the present). // OP's example defaults to the _attired_ (ie the actual dressing has been finished, leaving the resulting clothed state) sense, as you say.